# Compute $\mathbf v \mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf v^\top$ in a numerically stable way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, inverse

I've read that you should avoid computing a matrix inverse, as you generally don't need to, but I don't know the best way to avoid it.  I need to compute:

$$x = \mathbf v \mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf v^\top$$

where $x$ is a scalar, $\mathbf v$ is a row vector, $\mathbf A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix (but perhaps with eigenvalues close to $0$) and ${}^\top$ means transpose.

I'm using `numpy/scipy` so feel free to express an answer using their functions.

---

EDIT:

Any pros/cons of the least squares approach versus doing an eigenvector decomposition?

Comment: The "safe" version of the least squares approach (SVD) and the eigendecomposition are the same, as I noted in percusse's answer. The "fast" version (QR, or Cholesky) is faster ;) , but a bit riskier if as you say your matrix has potentially tiny eigenvalues...

Comment: @J.M., thanks, speed is not an issue with me so I will go the safe route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v*inv(A) is the same as v/A in matlab notation, which uses a linear (least squares) solver rather than calculating the inverse.

So I guess I would use:

```
numpy.dot( numpy.linalg.lstsq( A, v ), v )
```

I'm not sure if the row versus column will matter to the software, but you can freely transpose things without changing anything important as A is symmetric (so if it cannot detect you passing the wrong kind of vector in, then use `numpy.transpose`).

- [`dot` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot)
- [`lstsq` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq)
- [`transpose` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy.transpose)

If you have many different v for a single A, then you can use:

- [`cholesky`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html)

to get a better solver.  I didn't see any such solver built-in to numpy, but things like matlab (and hopefully octave) would automatically switch to a faster solver for the SPD case.

Comment: I found [cholesky](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html#numpy.linalg.cholesky) in the parallel directory: [decompositions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html#decompositions).

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that you should avoid computing a matrix inverse, as you generally don't need to.

This statement is incomplete. In general, you have no need for the inverse of a matrix as a separate entity. In most cases, you have something of the form $A^{-1}x$, where $x$ is a column vector, and computing $A^{-1}$ is as computationally intensive as computing $A^{-1}x$. So, if you don't need the inverse by itself, it is not worth calculating it in isolation.

Now when computing $A^{-1}x$, your actually computing the solution to $Ax = b$, and all numerical algorithms treat it as such. So, you need to use [numpy.linalg.solve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve), as follows

```
x = numpy.linalg.solve( A, v )
numpy.dot( v, x )
```

Or, in one line

```
numpy.dot( v, numpy.linalg.solve( A, v ) )
```

This differs from Jack's solution, in that [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) solves $A x = b$ by minimizing $|b - A x|^2_2$, while numpy.linalg.solve uses an LU decomposition and it assumes that $A$ has full rank. (Being symmetric implies that it is square.)

Answer (score 1):

If the computational cost is not an issue, you can find the [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A=U\Sigma V^T$ and only invert $\Sigma$ then do the multiplication as $$x=vU\Sigma^{-1}(Vv)^T$$

Comment: The $\Sigma^{-1}$ can either be a true inverse or a pseudoinverse (reciprocate those diagonal entries larger than machine epsilon times the matrix norm), of course. Then again, since $A$ is symmetric positive definite, the SVD and the eigendecomposition are one and the same.